# Destruct a Reference Member Initialized from Factory Method

Tags: c++, reference, member, factory-method

To initialize a reference member without a reference to an external entity passed to the constructor of the containing class, a factory method can be used, like this:

```
struct B
{
    B() : a(new_a()) {}
    // factory
    a& new_a()
    {
        A* a = new A;
        return *a;
    }
    A& a;
};
```

However, of course `B::a` won't be destroyed when `B`'s lifetime ends, because it is a reference. But there is not access to `B::a` outside of `B`. So this is a memory leak. To fix this one can call `A::~A()` from `B::~B()`

```
B::~B() {a.~A();}
```

But I have read manually calling destructors was a no-no, so putting a call to `A::~A()` in the destructor of `B::~B()` falls flat, or does it?

Is there cleaner solution?

Comment: I think you need to rethink your design. For example, *why* must you have a reference? Can't you have an actual instance (which is really what I recommend)? Or a pointer (or rather a smart pointer)?

Comment: `return *a;` dereferences the pointer. `a` winds up with a copy of the `new`ed `A`, but the `new`ed `A` is leaked.

Comment: @user4581301 no. `new_a` returns a reference (assuming the return type is supposed to be `A&` not `a&`) and that binds directly to `B::a`. There is no copy.

Comment: Right. Reference all through. My bad.

Answer (score 4):

`delete &a;` in `B`'s destructor should do the job correctly to avoid a memory leak.

I'd better recommend the factory function rather should return a [`std::unique_ptr<A>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) though. Or you simply use a plain instance of `A` as `B`'s member.

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner solution would be to avoid converting a pointer into a reference.  The reference `A& a;` data member implies that `struct B` doesn't own the object that `a` references.  However, in your case it does, and it creates confusion.

You should prefer references (and raw pointers) for non-owning relationships and smart pointers or value objects for owning relationships.

For example, `std::unique_ptr<A> a;` data member here would clearly show the ownership intent, and as a bonus, `a` will be automatically released when `B` is destroyed.  You don't even need to write anything in `~B()` destructor.

As a result, your `new a()` function can be written like this:

`std::unique_ptr<A> new_a() { return {new A()}; }`

In fact you don't need to write `new_a()`.  The C++ standard library already defines a function like this for you: `std::make_unique`.

Comment: `unique_ptr` has an explicit constructor, so you need to do `return std::unique_ptr<A>{new A};` (or `return std::make_unique<A>();` as you said).